# Creating reusable infrastructure for repeated testing - what OOP concept am I missing?

Tags: c#, oop

I am building some infrastructure to test a group of pricing engines that use various financial instruments. My problem is that I essentially have 3 layers of infrastructure, and do not know what the most suitable way to organize this infrastructure in OOP fashion is.

To explain my current design:

- One lone TestClass `PricingEngineTests`

  - Method `createStuff()` which:

    - initializes some test tool objects `A`,`B`, `C`, ... , `Z`
    - these testing objects are passed as parameters in various unique combinations to initialize test financial instrument objects `1`,`2`, ... , `50`
  - Separate TestMethods for each respective pricing engine, which:

    - call `createStuff()`
    - use some unique combination of test tool objects `A` to `Z` and test financial instruments `1` to `50` to initialize objects of that particular pricing engine
    - subsequently perform tests on that respective pricing engine's methods with the created pricing engine objects

Now **my problem** is that every single test method must call `createStuff()`, which takes some time to build all of `A` to `Z` and `1` to `50` only to use some much smaller unique subset of the infrastructure it creates every time. This is clearly a flaw in my design to me.

The logic behind this design structure was so that I can test each pricing engine independently from one another, without duplicating large amounts of infrastructure-creating code in the beginning of each respective test method by scrapping `createStuff()` altogether.

I know my design is poor, however I do not know how to fix it in object-oriented fashion... how could I more efficiently build this infrastructure such that I can test each pricing engine independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just call `createStuff()` from a `[TestFixtureSetup]` method (its name will depend on which unit testing framework you are using) which is run only once for the current test run, so reducing the amount of initialization from n (where n is the number of tests) to 1.

Obviously this relies on the setup being the same for every test, but it seems from your question that it should be.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with C#, and knew it must be something this simple... that's exactly what I need. Many thanks.